# UIButton Click Event not working if I add UITapGestureRecognizer in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitapgesturerecognizer

On my login page, if I focus to UITextEdit for entering email and password, keyboard appears and login page scroll up. And I add this code for remove keyboard if I touch outside of keyboard.

```
extension UIViewController {
    func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
    
    @objc func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
        })
    }
}
```

And on my viewDidLoad() function, I added it like this.

```
override func viewDidLoad() 
{
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //TODO
        self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
       ...
}
```

It works well, But If I click login button when keyboard is still opening, dismisskeyboard() function works but btnClick function doesn't work.

```
@IBAction func LoginBtnClick(_ sender: Any) 
{
        print("loginBtn")
        //...
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add the gesture to main viewController's view add a full screen subview below UIButton and add the gesture to it

Answer (score 3):

I actually solved it a little different way (I had the same problem on my login screen).  I just moved the dismissing/animating of the keyboard into an async block with a tiny delay, because it seemed like with the tap recognizer, it was picking up the touch down, but **not** the touch up inside the button, likely because the screen had already started to animate the dismissal of the keyboard.

```
@objc func dismissKeyboard() {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(100)) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: hope you get this message - that is a one in a million tip!  great thinking, cheers. sending bounty :)

Answer (score 2):

I have tested it using following code:

```
import UIKit

extension UIViewController {
    func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    @objc func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
        })
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    fileprivate let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 50))
    fileprivate let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 200, width: 150, height: 50))

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        view.addSubview(textField)
        textField.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        view.addSubview(button)
        button.setTitle("Press me", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(a), for: .touchUpInside)

        hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
    }

    @objc func a() {
        print(">>>> pressed")
    }
}
```

The code in `a` gets called. Thus I assume that there is something else in your code that causes the button not to work. Perhaps you forgot to link the `button` to the `@IBAction` `LoginBtnClick(_:)` - check if the connection is really there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. func a() was called when keyboard open?

Comment: Yes. Although when I pressed the button, the `dismissKeyboard` was called too, so not only the button action was called, but also the keyboard gets dismissed. You can try my code by simply presenting that `ViewController` somewhere.

Comment: Did you confirm that `@IBAction` is connected to the button in storyboards? Just as an experiment, add an `@IBOutlet` to the viewController, and then use `addTarget` as I did to link the button to the `LoginBtnClick` method programmatically. Sometimes there are glitches in storyboards, maybe it shows there is connection, but it does not really wire it up.

Comment: But login button works if there's no keyboard on the screen. I checked your code and it works. Very strange and I am little confused. Maybe there's something wrong on my code.

Comment: Do you do anything when the keyboard appears? Show that code too

Comment: I added new UIView and add gesture to it. Thanks for your time and your help. Maybe your answer is also correct. As I said, there's some problem on my code. Anyway, I solve the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I added a button over the view of view controller (be sure that your textfield is in front of the button).
Then, I implemented the UITextFieldDelegate to enable/disable the button.
Something like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet private weak var myTextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet private weak var myButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.myTextfield.delegate = self
    }
    
    // MARK: - UITextFieldDelegate
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        self.myButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
    
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        self.myButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }
    
    // MARK: - Action functions.
    @IBAction private func onButtonAction() {
        self.myTextfield.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```